# PHP issue with htmlentities in 5.6 and 7.0

Tags: php, html-entities

I have recently upgraded from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.0 on AWS EC2 instance. I have a code as below

```
stripslashes(htmlentities(self::$_variable));
```

in PHP 5.6 is working as required but in 7.0 it is giving following warning

```
<b>Warning</b>:  htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

Now I need  to know it is due to version change or anything else. Any documentation or link in support of your answer will be really helpful.

Comment: Have you checked what is the value in `self::$_variable`? Its clear that it is an array. You should debug why its coming as array.

Comment: Sounds more like a change in error reporting than a change in `htmlentities()`. Which has not changed.

Comment: check type of $_variable, where you are getting this warning.

Comment: I have checked the variable and it is an array but it working fine in 5.6 and not in 7.0

@LovepreetSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others suggested in comments: The `self::$_variable` contains an array so `htmlentities` fails when run no matter what PHP version (greater or equal to 4) you use.

See an online example [here](https://3v4l.org/57nHT). The documentation link you requested can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

For changes between PHP 5.6 and 7.0 see [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php). For backwards-compatibility breaks see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php). Or generally [all the section](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php).

Comment: Error reporting can be set to ignore an array to string conversion in either 5.6 or 7.0. The difference isnt in the version but the default error level in the different php installations.

Comment: @chiliNUT: The change in error reporting will not fix the problem. On the other hand, proving the function works the same and providing links to articles to study can help to fix it. Or do you really think doing `echo @htmlentities($smth);` or changing error reporting will be a better solution just to make it work the broken way as w/ 5.6?